# Recognize unknown options in Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, getopt-long

How can you recognize unknown options using `Getopt::Long`?

I tried `<>`, but it did not work as expected.  Consider:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Getopt::Long;

my $help='';
GetOptions ('help' => \$help,'<>' => \&usage);
usage() if $help;

usage() if @ARGV != 1;

my $fn=pop;

say "FileName: $fn";

sub usage {
    say "Unknown option: @_" if ( @_ );
    say "Usage: $0 <filename>";
    say "       $0 --help";
    say "";
    exit
}
```

I would like to print `Unknown option` only if there is an unrecognized option (in this case, anything other than `--help`).  But, now it thinks the filename is an unrecognized option.

Comment: Are you saying you want to print `Unknown option` for things like `--foo` or `-foo` but treat `foo` as a filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your `usage` function if `GetOptions` fails.  [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) will print `Unknown option` for you (to STDERR):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Getopt::Long;

my $help='';
GetOptions ('help' => \$help) or usage();
usage() if $help;

usage() if @ARGV != 1;

my $fn=pop;

say "FileName: $fn";

sub usage {
    say "Usage: $0 <filename>";
    say "       $0 --help";
    say "";
    exit
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Start using pod documentation as the core modules [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and [`Pod::Usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) work very well together.  Can get the behavior you want without having to create helper methods to accomplish it:

Here's an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Basename qw(basename);
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);
use Readonly;
use version;

use strict;
use warnings;

Readonly my $VERSION => qv('0.0.1');
Readonly my $EXE => basename($0);

GetOptions(
    'version'   => \my $version,
    'usage'     => \my $usage,
    'help|?'    => \my $help,
    'man'       => \my $man,
) or pod2usage(-verbose => 0);
pod2usage(-verbose => 0) if $usage;
pod2usage(-verbose => 1) if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $man;

if ($version) {
    print "$EXE v$VERSION\n";
    exit;
}

## Check for File
pod2usage("$EXE: No filename specified.\n") unless @ARGV;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
pod2usage("$EXE: $file is a directory.\n") if -d $file;
pod2usage("$EXE: $file is not writable.\n") if !-w $file;


#....
print "Hello World\n";
#....

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

hello.pl - Mirrors a script using pod

=head1 SYNOPSIS

./hello.pl [FILE]


=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item --version

Print the version information

=item --usage

Print the usage line of this summary

=item --help

Print this summary.

=item --man

Print the complete manpage

=back


=head1 DESCRIPTION

Sometimes a programmer just enjoys a bit of documentation.
They can't help themselves, it makes them feel accomplished.

=head1 AUTHOR

Written by A Simple Coder
```

Output:

```
>perl hello.pl --test
Unknown option: test
Usage:
    ./hello.pl [FILE]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I am starting to learn perl, so I was not aware of POD documentation..It seems great.